# Ubuntu 14.04 - Fake a higher resolution

Tags: 14.04, display-resolution

Is there a way to make 1366x768 look more like 1440x810? I remember reading about a way to do it on Windows, but I don't know if it can be replicated on Ubuntu.

EDIT: This is my xrandr output,

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768       59.8*+
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: ...wut?  you mean you want your screen to have smaller stuff on it with the same resolution?

Comment: @Deryck Yeah, because I like my things smaller.

Comment: You can adjust the sizes of the launcher etc in settings, probably the fonts as well in one of the tweak tools - do you just want stuff on the screen to be smaller? Any new resolution would need to be the same aspect ratio as well. What is the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: then all you have to do is use that higher resolution.  If you can't*** because of hardware limitations, then what you're hoping for is not going to work either.  At that point you'll just have to go even smaller

Comment: @Deryck My monitor’s max resolution is 1366x768, but I remember Windows had a way to do it by messing with the DPI in the registry or something.

Comment: Add it to your question using the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/491770/edit) button - its impossible to read...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can find an explanation in this [link](http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/linux%3afake_a_higher_resolution_in_linux)

Basically, you have to type in your terminal:

```
xrandr --output Monitor_Name --mode 1366x768 --scale scale_factor1xscale_factor2 --panning 1440z810
```

Note, however, that your scale factor is

1440/1366 = 1.054172767.

810/768= 1.0546875

As you note, both the width and height isn't a good number. The rescaling may look weird. It would be good for you to find a resolution where you have a "better" number to scale.

For example: 1024 to 1536 has a scale factor of 1.50.

Give it a try.

If the fonts looks too small, you can use Unity Tweak Tool to scale just them.

Type

```
xrandr
```

in your terminal to get your monitor name (probably it's LVDS1 or something like that). It also say the maximum resolution you can set there.

Comment: Actually, one more thing. Here's a scenario: I have a 1366x768 monitor, and I want it to look like it's actually 1502x844. What scale factor do I use/What command do I use, because currently the faked display does not fit onscreen.

Comment: I never used the command, but as I am concerned, the first --mode 1366x768 is your maximum natural resolution. So make the division to get scale factor using then. The second one should be the desired resolution. 
It doesn't make sense to use the current resolution rather the natural, because the rollback would be a pain to scale.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it, I'm not super-good with math. >_< What exactly am I supposed to do to get the correct command, because currently it just goes off the screen, rather than scale down to fit.

Comment: try --mode 1366x768 --s1.1x1.09 --panning 1502z844

Comment: It still goes offscreen. :( I'm sorry if I'm bothering you to much, I'd just really like this to work.

Comment: its cool lol.
reset your resolution (--mode 1366x768 --scale 1x1 --panning 1366x768). try playig with the command without the "panning" part. you can do xrandr --help aswell to have the options you have. as I said, i never played with this command so I'm not very good on it =P

Answer (score 0):

or you can just tweak DPI settings to match your taste.

On my Ubuntu 14.10, i can find the DPI setting in:

**Setting_manager** >> **Appearance** >> Fonts(tab)

[image]